# Prime analogue of Champernowne's constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Are any non-trivial properties known about the constant 0.2357111317192329... that is obtained by catenating the digits of sequence of prime numbers in base 10 or in other bases, especially whether it is normal?

Comment: In base 10 this is called the _Copeland–Erdős constant;_ it is normal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland–Erdős_constant and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Copeland-ErdosConstant.html and https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183509721

Comment: @FredRohrer your comment would be an acceptable answer to me.

Comment: An immediate consequence of the Dirichlet's Theorem on arithmetic progression is that for each $n \geq 1$ there are infinitely many prime numbers starting with $n$ as the first digits.

Comment: @NickS With "first digits" do you mean the leftmost or the rightmost digits? Citing Dirichlet I would assume you mean rightmost, in which case this is only true for $n$ not divisible by $2$ or $5$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, sorry I was imprecise... What I meant, you add some digits after $n$ and apply the DT, you can easily do this and keep the new number relatively prime to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base 10 this is called the *[Copeland–Erdős constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant);* it is normal. See [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183509721).

Comment: Actually, much more general results are known for the normality of numbers which are obtained by concatenating certain function values (at integers, or at primes). See for example Nakai, Y., Shiokawa, I.: Normality of numbers generated by the values of polynomials at primes. Acta Arith. 81 (1997), no. 4, 345–356.